# How to receive data from multithread in Java using Custom Event Listener?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, streaming

I have a about 500 threads(assume that call as X for all these threads), and these threads receive data from different restful services continuously. Also, i have 20 threads(assume that call as Y for all these threads) for receive data returned from other threads(from X).

Should I use BlockingQueue or Custom Event Listener? Which one is better?

Also, there should be no data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Limitation of using **BlockingQueue**, it has a queue with a threshold point. Post this point, no more threads can be processed. In a scenario, Lost Data couldn't be recovered when exceptions (failures) are thrown by bunch of threads (X or Y) (which couldn't be processed again).

However, **Custom Event Listener** is preferable approach where acknowledgment can be done for all thread, and in case of thread exception (failure), we can retrieve lost data by using some reprocess mechanism.

Can use *ReactiveX*(**Observable**) library for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a **messaging queue( like Kafka, rabbitmq)**
which work like a data holder between the threads x and Y. 
You put data in queue from x's and fetch/process the data via Y's which is **asynchronous**.

You should opt for this as even in Event Listener if we consider number of x 500 and y 20. then even for each call of x's there be 20 call (assume).which can become a bottle neck on heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

BlockingQueue is better (usually).